# how to rotate an image if captured by custom camera for all devices in android

Tags: android

I am building an app.

I am using custom camera to capture an image but after capturing image I save it using output stream. On next activity if I fetch same image using path at put it on an imageview than it is rotated. Some device it is 90 degree and in some devices it is 180 degree for front camera and similarly for back camera.
I have use ExifInterface before saving image but its return 0 always

My code to save image by custom camera is:

```
 class SaveAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        private Context context;
        private byte[] bytes;
        private File imageFile;

        // here bytes is for capture image bytes
        SaveAsync(Context context,byte[] bytes,File imageFile){
            this.context=context;
            this.bytes=bytes;
            this.imageFile=imageFile;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            OutputStream output = null;

            try {
                output = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                output.write(bytes);

                output.flush();
                output.close();

                sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri
                        .parse("file://" + imageFile)));


            }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Camera2","IO  in async : "+ex);
                //Toast.makeText(context,"File not find",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch (Exception ex){
                Log.e("Camera2","Exp in async : "+ex);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
Matrix mat = new Matrix();
mat.postRotate(90);
Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), mat, true)
```

1. Convert your file to bitmap
2. Rotate Bitmap
3. Save rotated bitmap to file on storage
4. load from storage

Comment: i tried this, but the situation is, if i have two mobile A and B, if i rotate image by 90 degree in my code than it works for mobile A  but in case of mobile B it is rotates image by 180 degree .... so i need a common code for all devices .. thanks

Comment: You can use **ExIfInterface** class to check the bitmap image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method which can be use to check for the image rotation:

```
private Bitmap checkRotation(String filePath, Bitmap scaledBitmap) {
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                    true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return scaledBitmap;
    }
```